# One vs several opportunities per client - What do I miss if I go for only one?

Tags: opportunity

I have a situation where my client wants to keep only one opportunity per client, with the status rolling forward and backwards instead of creating new opportunities every time.

From an input perspective, it seems easier for users.

**What Salesforce features will I lose if we decide going this way?**

I have already considered campaign influence, as it won't make sense... anything else?

Comment: It depends a lot on the business itself. For example, is there a clear beginning and end to these opportunities? What would "every time" mean in the context of the customer relationship?

Comment: Although opportunities represent services to be enjoyed in a given year. It does not matter if one or more service is won on a specific year: as soon as the first service is won for the year the opportunity is considered to be won for that year.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Namely, you lose reporting and data quality. How much business did you do with Acme in 2016? If you have multiple opportunities, this question is a cinch. If you're recycling the same record over and over again, you can't answer this very basic question. This is only the beginning of the problems they'll encounter. They won't be able to do things like figure out who the top sales performers are, or figure out which products/services were the most successful, forecast the potential sales for the next quarter/year, etc. You lose all chronological information when you do this, and that data is often vital in making future business decisions. Also, as products like Einstein come in to play, Einstein won't be able to make proper educated forecasts without this data. Simply put, you're going to have garbage data, and ultimately defeat the purpose of using a CRM.

Comment: These are very valid reasons and metrics to consider. Are there other **features** that we would be missing?

Comment: @JohnSmith As you've observed, along with Campaigns, I'm pretty sure they would have to intentionally cripple Leads as well (no conversion of leads with opportunities), but this really falls back down to reporting problems. Which I cannot possibly overstate enough. Any CRM with no reporting capability is no CRM at all. While Salesforce arguably doesn't have the *best* reporting, it does have *very good* reporting, but it's all junk without real data.